# вывод данных из mysql в php

Tags: php, mysql

Возможно ли сделать вывод данных из mysql в php вот так:

```
    {"2a6a5dc0e17a9a00ef74e57de3025922":2,"968a3efe82e7a44db200428eb9519cf6":2,"bb90e4b48bf3655834c9cc18f607c05e":2}
```

на данный момент выводится так:

```
    2a6a5dc0e17a9a00ef74e57de3025922968a3efe82e7a44db200428eb9519cf6bb90e4b48bf3655834c9cc18f607c05e
```

сам код:

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 

$query ="SELECT url FROM sync";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); 
if($result)
{

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo $row[0];
    }


    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Возможно. Например, через вывод дополнительных символов.

Comment: Вам в помощь `json_encode($array);`

Comment: Спасибо всем за советы. Проблема решилась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выводите не сразу с echo. А помещаете вывод в массив. В конце скрипта с помощью `echo json_encode($array)` преобразуете массив в json и выводите его.

```
$answer=[];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $answer[]=$row[0];
}
echo json_encode($answer);
```